# Creating a library with book objects and member objects

Tags: java

I've just started programming recently and have ran into a few minor errors. I'm creating a library object which holds references to book objects and member objects, however I'm having trouble accessing methods from the member class and using them in the library class without errors popping up in the LibraryTester class. This is what I've coded

Library class

```
package assignment;

import java.nio.channels.MembershipKey;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.omg.Messaging.SyncScopeHelper;

public class Library {

    // Declared an array list of type book
    private ArrayList<Book> Books;
    private MemberList members;;
    public Library(ArrayList<Book> Books, Member member) {
        this.Books = Books;
        this.members=members;
    };

    public void displayBooks() {
        System.out.println("\t\t\t-----The Current Books in the library are-----");
        for (int i = 0; i < Books.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("\n" + "\t\t" + Books.get(i).getTitle() + "\t\t\t" + "\n\t\tAuthor: "
                    + Books.get(i).getAuthor() + "\n\t\tThis Books ID is: " + Books.get(i).getBookID() + "\t\t\t\t\t\t"
                    + "\n\t\tIs this book on loan? " + Books.get(i).getOnLoan() + "\t\t\t\t\t"
                    + "\n\t\tThe number of times which this book has been loaned: " + Books.get(i).getNumOfLoans()
                    + "\t\t");
        }
    }

    // method to remove permanently a book object
    public void removeBook() // the parameter that is passed through
                                // is the book id of the book that is to
                                // be removed

    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int bookID = 0;

        boolean successful = false;
        try {
            do {

                System.out.println("Please enter the book ID of the book you wish to delete");
                bookID = input.nextInt();
                for (int i = 0; i < Books.size(); i++) {
                    if (bookID == Books.get(i).getBookID())

                    {
                        System.out.println("The Book " + Books.get(i).getTitle() + " was removed");
                        Books.remove(i);
                        successful = true;
                        break;

                    }

                }
                if (!successful) {
                    System.out.println("Book ID " + bookID + " does not exist");
                }

            } while (successful == false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Invalid input" + "\nYou have been returned to the main menu");
        }
    }

    public void editBook() {

        boolean successful = false;
        try {
            do {
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Please enter the book ID of the book who's details you wish to change");
                int bookID = sc.nextInt();
                sc.nextLine();
                for (int i = 0; i < Books.size(); i++) {
                    if (Books.get(i).getBookID() == bookID) {

                        System.out.println("Please enter the new name of the book:");
                        String newTitle = sc.nextLine();
                        Books.get(i).setTitle(newTitle);
                        System.out.println("Please enter the name of the author of the book:");
                        String newAuthor = sc.nextLine();
                        Books.get(i).setAuthor(newAuthor);
                        System.out.println("Change of book details successful" + "\nNew book title: " + newTitle
                                + "\nNew author: " + newAuthor);
                        successful = true;
                    }

                }

                if (!successful) {
                    System.out.println("This book does not exist ");
                }

            } while (successful == false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Invalid input" + "\nYou have been returned to the main menu");
        }
    }

    public void addBook() {

        boolean successful = false;
        int bookID = 0;
        String title = "";
        String author = "";
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {

            System.out.println("Please assign a 3 digit number for the books ID ");
            bookID = input.nextInt();
            input.nextLine();
            if(bookID > 99 && bookID <1000){
            for (int i = 0; i < Books.size(); i++) {
                if(Books.get(i).getBookID()!= bookID){
                    successful = true;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("This book ID already exists ");
                }
            }
            } else { System.out.println("You must enter a number between 99 and 1000 ");
            }
        } while (successful == false);

        do {
            System.out.println("Please enter the name of book");
            title = input.nextLine();

            for (int i = 0; i < Books.size(); i++) {
                if (Books.get(i).getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(title)) {
                    System.out.println("ERROR: This book already exists");
                    successful = false;
                } else {
                    successful = true;
                }
            }
        } while (successful == false);

        do {
            System.out.println("Please enter the author of the book");
            author = input.nextLine();

            successful = true;

        } while (successful == false);
        Book Book = new Book(bookID, title, author, false, 0, 0);
        Books.add(Book);
        System.out.println(
                "Book creation succcessful:" + "\nTitle: " + title + "\nAuthor: " + author + "\nBook ID:" + bookID);
    }

    public void loanBook() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean successful = false;
        do {

            System.out.println(
                    "\nPlease enter the book ID of the book that you wish to take out (Press 9 to exit to the main menu)");
            int bookID = input.nextInt();
            if (bookID == 9) {
                successful = true;
                break;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < Books.size(); i++) {
                if (Books.get(i).getBookID() == bookID) {
                    do {
                        System.out.println("\nHow long would you like to loan the book for (20 Days maximum):");
                        int durationOnLoan = input.nextInt();
                        if (durationOnLoan <= 20 && 1 <= durationOnLoan) {
                            Books.get(i).setDurationOnLoan(durationOnLoan);
                            successful = true;
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("The number of days you have entered is invalid");
                        }
                    } while (successful == false);

                    System.out.println("\nThe book " + Books.get(i).getTitle() + " is now on loan");
                    Books.get(i).setOnLoan(true);

                    Books.get(i).setNumOfLoan(Books.get(i).getNumOfLoans() + 1);
                    successful = true;
                }

            }

            if (successful == false) {

                System.out.println("This book does not exist ");
            }

        } while (successful == false);
    }

    public void returnBook() {

        boolean successful = false;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            do {

                System.out.println(
                        "Please enter the book ID of the book you wish to return (Press 9 to exit to the main menu");
                int bookID = input.nextInt();
                input.nextLine();
                if (bookID == 9) {
                    successful = true;
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < Books.size(); i++) {
                    if (Books.get(i).getBookID() == bookID) {
                        if (Books.get(i).getOnLoan() == true) {
                            System.out.println("How long did you loan the book for?");
                            int durationOnLoan = input.nextInt();
                            if (durationOnLoan > Books.get(i).getDurationOnLoan()) {
                                durationOnLoan -= Books.get(i).getDurationOnLoan();
                                if (durationOnLoan < 3) {

                                    System.out.println("You are " + durationOnLoan
                                            + " day(s) late in returning the book" + "\nYou have been fined £3."
                                            + "\n The book " + Books.get(i).getTitle() + " is now returned");
                                    successful = true;

                                } else {

                                    System.out.println("You are " + durationOnLoan + " days late in returning the book"
                                            + "\nYou have been fined £6.");
                                    System.out
                                            .println("The book " + Books.get(i).getTitle() + " has now been returned");
                                    successful = true;

                                }
                            } else {
                                Books.get(i).setOnLoan(false);
                                System.out.println("The book " + Books.get(i).getTitle() + " has now been returned");
                                successful = true;
                            }

                        } else if (Books.get(i).getOnLoan() == false) {
                            System.out.println("\nThis book was not on loan");
                            System.out.println("\nYou have been returned to the main menu");
                            successful = true;
                        }
                    } else if (successful == false) {
                        System.out.println("This book does not exist");
                    }
                }

            } while (successful == false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Invalid input" + "\nYou have been returned to the main menu");

        }
    }

}
```

MemberList class

```
package assignment;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MemberList {

    private ArrayList<Member> Members;

    public MemberList(ArrayList<Member> Members) {
        this.Members = Members;
    }

    public void addNewMember() {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean successful = false;
        int memberID = 0;
        String memberName = "";
        int memberAge;
        String address;
        int contactNumber;

        System.out.println("\t\tCreate new member");
        do {


            System.out.println("Please enter your full name:");
            memberName = input.nextLine();
            if (!input.hasNextInt()) {
                successful =true;
            } else {
                input.next();
                System.out.println("Your name cannot contain a number");
            }


        } while (successful == false);

        do {
            try{
            input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("please create your unique 2 digit member ID");
            memberID = input.nextInt();
            for (int i = 0; i < Members.size(); i++) {
                if (Members.get(i).getMemberID() == memberID) {
                    System.out.println("This member ID is already in use");
                    successful =false;
                }
                if (memberID <= 9 || memberID > 99) {
                    System.out.println("PLease enter 2 digit ID (between 10 and 100) ");
                }
                if(Members.get(i).getMemberID() != memberID && memberID > 9 && memberID < 100) {
                    successful = true;
                }
            }

            } catch(NumberFormatException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid input");
            }
        } while (successful == false);

        do{ 
            System.out.println("Please enter your age: ");
            memberAge = input.nextInt();
            if(!input.hasNextInt())
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid input");
            } else{successful =true;}

        }while(successful == false);

        do{

            System.out.println("Please enter your adress");
            address = input.nextLine();
            successful =true;
        }while(successful==false);

        do {
            System.out.println("please enter your contact number:");
            contactNumber = input.nextInt();
            if(!input.hasNextInt())
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid input");
            } else{successful = true;}

        }while(successful==false);

        Member newMember = new Member(memberID,memberName,memberAge,0,0,address,contactNumber);
        Members.add(newMember);


    }

    public void displayMembers()
    {
        System.out.println("\t\t\t-----The current members in the library are-----");
        for (int i = 0; i < Members.size(); i++) 
        {
                        System.out.println("\n" + "\t\t" + Members.get(i).getMemberName() + "\t\t\t" + "\n\t\tMember ID: "
                    + Members.get(i).getMemberID() + "\n\t\tAge: " + Members.get(i).getMemberAge() + "\t\t\t\t\t\t"
                    + "\n\t\tAddress: " + Members.get(i).getAddress() + "\t\t\t\t\t"
                    + "\n\t\tContact number: " + Members.get(i).getContactNumber()
                    + "\t\t" + "\n\t\tNumber of books loaned: " + Members.get(i).getNumOfBooksLoaned() 
                    + "\t\t" + "\n\t\tNumber of Late Fees: " + Members.get(i).getPenalties());
        }
    }
}
```

LibraryTester Class

```
package assignment;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class LibraryTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String title = "";
        String author = "";
        int bookID = 0;


        ArrayList<Member> List = new ArrayList<Member>();
        MemberList memberlist = new MemberList(List){};

        Member John = new Member(10,"John McLaughlin", 44, 5, 0,"75 B Loughbeg Road Toomebridge",123456789);
        List.add(John); 
        Member Cathy = new Member(11,"Cathy McLaughlin", 43, 7, 0,"75 B Loughbeg Road Toomebridge",123456789);
        List.add(Cathy);


        ArrayList<Book> list = new ArrayList<Book>();
        Library library = new Library(list, );


        Book HarryPotter = new Book(100, "Harry Potter and The Philosopher's Stone", "J.K Rowling", false, 5, 0);
        list.add(HarryPotter);
        Book theOriginOfSpecies = new Book(101, "The Origin Of Species", "Charles Darwin", false, 3, 0);
        list.add(theOriginOfSpecies);
        Book LOTR = new Book(102, "The Lord of The Rings: The Fellowship of The Ring", "J.R.R Tolkien", false,7,0);
        list.add(LOTR);

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


        boolean B = true;

        while (B == true) {

            System.out.println("  \nMenu  ");
            System.out.println("Press 1 to add a book");
            System.out.println("Press 2 to edit a books details");
            System.out.println("Press 3 to delete a book");
            System.out.println("Press 4 to take out a book on loan");
            System.out.println("Press 5 to return a book");
            System.out.println("Press 6 to see all the books in the library");
            System.out.println("Press 7 to become a member");
            System.out.println("Press 8 to see the members of the library");
            System.out.println("Press 9 to exit the program");

            switch (input.nextInt()) {

            case 1:

                library.addBook();
                B = true;
                break;

            case 2:
                library.displayBooks();
                library.editBook();
                B = true;
                break;

            case 3:

                library.displayBooks();
                library.removeBook();

                B = true;
                break;

            case 4:
                library.displayBooks();
                library.loanBook();

                B = true;
                break;

            case 5:
                library.displayBooks();
                library.returnBook();
                break;
            case 6:

                library.displayBooks();
                B = true;
                break;
            case 7:
                memberlist.addNewMember();
                break;
            case 8:
                memberlist.displayMembers();
                B = true;
                break;
            case 9:
                System.out.println("Exiting .....");
                System.exit(1);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("You have not entered a valid option");
                break;

            }

        }
    }

}
```

The error occurs at the code

```
Library library = new Library(list , ) {
};
```

I'm not sure what to put after the comma, I've tried everything and nothing seems to work. Any thoughts?

EDIT

Edited Library class

```
package assignment;

import java.nio.channels.MembershipKey;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.omg.Messaging.SyncScopeHelper;

public class Library {

    // Declared an array list of type book
    private ArrayList<Book> Books;
    private ArrayList<Member> members;;
    public Library(ArrayList<Book> Books, ArrayList<Member> member) {
        this.Books = Books;
        this.members=member;
    };
```

Edited LibraryTester class

```
ArrayList<Member> List = new ArrayList<Member>();
MemberList memberList = new MemberList(List){};


ArrayList<Book> list = new ArrayList<Book>();
Library library = new Library(list, memberList ){};
```

The error says "The constructor Library(ArrayList, MemberList) is undefined"  But i've changed the relevant things in the library class?

Comment: What errors are you seeing? Post the full error messages as they contain much useful information and often tell you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: Your Library constructor expects a List of Books and an Member:
`Library library = new Library(list , new Member();`

Comment: Why are you importing (and not using) `java.nio.channels.MembershipKey` and `org.omg.Messaging.SyncScopeHelper`? Also very important: variables and fields start with a *lowercase* letter; use `ArrayList<Member> members` and `ArrayList<Book> books` instead of what you're doing now.

Comment: ahhh i see what you mean @Cir0X, 'Library library = new Library(list, new Member(10,"Joe Blogs", 44, 5, 0,"Bleaker Street",123456789) ){};' works, but is there any way that I can have this a user input to store multiple members?

Comment: @C.Darwin You want to create a Library with a Member list?
You need to change your Library constructor to:
`public Library(ArrayList<Book> Books, ArrayListMember> members) {`
And you can now create a Library Object like this: `Library library = new Library(list, memberList);`
And the memberList can you create with:
`ArrayList<Member> memberList = new ArrayList<Member>();`

Comment: You should avoid capitalizing the ArrayList `Books` in your Library class. Use camel-case for all non-final variables and methods. As far as your `loanBook()` method is concerned, if `Books` is empty, then you've effectively created an infinite loop.

Comment: @Cir0X  That almost works ! Just one thing, i'll edit the original post

Comment: Sorry, I meant `editBook()`. The only way out is to enter invalid input so an exception is thrown.

Comment: It's not working because class MemberList != ArrayList

Comment: @Monekygrinder should I use try catch for that or something else?

Comment: No try catch. You should rename `ArrayList <Member> List` to `ArrayList<Member> memberList`. Or change your constructor to take MemberList as opposed to ArrayList

Comment: @C.Darwin You need to change your constructor in the Library class to: `public Library(ArrayList<Book> Books, MemberList members) {`

Comment: sorry @Monkeygrinder , i was referring to the `editBook()` method, but that worked ! thanks!

Comment: With regards to the editBook, you could use the method isEmpty(), e.g. `if (books.isEmpty())`, and if that is true, then you can do something like `System.out.println("there are no books");` then add a `return` statement. There's not much point in asking the user if they'd like to stop editing books when there are no books.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an array of Book and, a Member :

```
public Library(ArrayList<Book> Books, Member member)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Library class is having the constructor

```
    public Library(ArrayList<Book> Books, Member member){};
```

you can't just create a object as you are doing in LibraryTester class.
you need to pass the second parameter i.e, object of Member class.

Answer (score 0):

Here you miss a member:

```
 Library library = new Library(list, );
```

Try to add it like this creating an object of Member:

```
  Member memberlist = new Member(10,"Joe Blogs", 44, 5, 0,"Bleaker Street",123456789);
  Library library = new Library(list, memberlist);
```

Comment: I've tried ` Library library = new Library(list, memberlist);` and it doesn't work.

Comment: however `Library library = new Library(list , new Member(10,"Joe Blogs", 44, 5, 0,"Bleaker Street",123456789)){};` works

Comment: @C.Darwin try to take a look at above I think it's same thing, before you  should be sure memberlist is instance of Member.